# Need an engine for MMO mockup

Tags: mmo

What I *don't* need is an MMORPG engine, at the moment.

What I *do* need is a flexible easy-to-use engine that I can make a mock-up with. I don't need support for more than 10 players in an instance, so any multiplayer platform is probably fine.

I need an engine with which I can create the following core features:

- Waves of simple AI enemies that have specific objectives (move to point A, destroy target, move to point B). The units present can be between 50-200 in number.
- An over-the-shoulder view and the ability to control a team of 3 (like Mass Effect or the latest Dragon Age)
- Functioning inventory system

Right now, all I can really think of is Unreal or Source. Any other suggestions? Again, this is a proving mock-up, not an actual MMO.

I'm not terribly worried about the visual aspects as we just want to test mechanics.

*Note: Can write some scripts in Python, Ruby, or Lua, if necessary.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know you said you don't want a full-fledged MMORPG, but I can't think of something that will fit your bill without being big...

Here is a modern MMORPG, open sourced, including assets: [Ryzom](http://www.ryzom.com/en/). It should provide a good starting point for any open world multiplayer game.

Comment: Wow @_@. I had no idea that Ryzom went open source!! That could be an excellent place to muck around as a proving ground.

Comment: It was the aim from the start of the Ryzom project, it took a lot longer than hoped for, but here it is now. The FSF is rightly delighted with this ;)

Answer (score 5):

[Unity](http://unity3d.com/) - It will allow you quickly prototype what you're after. It has networking support, you can add flexible scripts to it to create your gameplay mechanics and it's got a lot of support and resources.

Comment: "Quickly" is very relative though.

Comment: Also, although the original poster said he could write scripts in Python, Ruby, or Lua, Unity offers C#, Boo, or Javascript!

Comment: @Ricket I completely agree. But there is a steeper learning curve to the OP's original thoughts with Unreal and Source. @Kylotan I did notice that, but again with Unreal using UnrealScript and Source using C++ (?) I made the assumption that the poster wanted to learn. To be completely honest, this was a lazy answer since I'm getting a little flustered with the amount of "What engine...?" questions on the site. Yeah, they may be for different intents and purposes, but essentially most are answered with Unity, it's just a matter of who answers it first.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to mod an existing game. Some people are even modding [Starcraft 2 to an MMO](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=roIOpHq0vUc), but that looks like a lot more work than modding a game that already has some RPG features.

There's an active [modding community](http://phrozenkeep.hugelaser.com/) for Diablo 2, so this might be a starting point?

I'm making this answer CW, because I'm not a modding expert and somebody might add some better suggestions for easy moddable RPGs or MMOs.

Comment: That was also my reasoning behind Source and Unreal. I probably would start as a HL2 mod or something, as opposed to a from-scratch project just for mock purposes. Thanks for the suggestion! Diablo does have a fair bit of interesting features that are conducive to this project.

Comment: If you are thinking of using Source you should take a look at garry's mod.

Answer (score 0):

About the only thing that will be this high-level is a tool like RPGMaker. Honestly if you just want to test it, mock something out in a top-down view using blue and red boxes or something.

Comment: I don't believe RPGmaker is capable of this sort of simulation. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Yeah, it would be a stretch at best. I think you are just going to have to write something yourself. You could also go the other direction, mock it up with index cards and dice or similar.